# Why does Xorg consume 200% cpu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, xorg

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system using Gnome3. I had some problems with my NVIDIA drivers when upgrading from 17.04. After a few iterations of purging and installing nouvea and nvidia proprietary drivers, I finally managed to install the proprietary ones and then switch to using the builtin Intel graphics.

I now notice that I have two Xorg programs running, one owned by gdm and one by my user account, dannas.

```
$ ps aux | grep Xorg
gdm       1105  187  0.2 263204 35868 tty1     Rl+  07:26   8:49 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/128/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
dannas    1476  1.6  1.1 899048 182292 tty2    Sl+  07:26   0:04 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

The one owned by gdm consumes lots of cpu.

```
$ pidstat -p 1105 1 | head
Linux 4.15.0-23-generic (dannas--dell-xp-15)    06/20/2018  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

07:29:02 AM   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest   %wait    %CPU   CPU  Command
07:29:03 AM   128      1105   94.00  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     7  Xorg
07:29:04 AM   128      1105   99.00  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     7  Xorg
07:29:05 AM   128      1105   86.00  100.00    0.00    1.00  100.00     7  Xorg
07:29:06 AM   128      1105   99.00  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     7  Xorg
07:29:07 AM   128      1105   86.00  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     7  Xorg
07:29:08 AM   128      1105  100.00   99.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     1  Xorg
07:29:09 AM   128      1105   93.00  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     1  Xorg
```

It appears to be reading all zeroes from fd 16.

```
$ sudo  strace -ttt -p 1105 2>&1 | head
strace: Process 1105 attached
1529472961.641488 read(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 40) = 36
1529472961.641525 epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=445731056, u64=94777489051888}}], 256, -1) = 1
1529472961.641547 read(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 40) = 40
1529472961.641568 epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=445731056, u64=94777489051888}}], 256, -1) = 1
1529472961.641588 read(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 40) = 29
1529472961.641609 epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=445731056, u64=94777489051888}}], 256, -1) = 1
1529472961.641627 read(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 40) = 28
1529472961.641647 epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=445731056, u64=94777489051888}}], 256, -1) = 1
1529472961.641666 read(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 40) = 27
```

When I attached gdb I didn't see anything in the backtraces besides calls to epoll_wait and read and generic names like, BlockHandler and WaitForSomething and WaitForSomething.

File descriptior 16 is a pipe...

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/1105/fd | grep 16
lr-x------ 1 gdm gdm 64 Jun 20 07:27 16 -> pipe:[29836]
```

Which is connected to the same Xorg program(?).

```
$ (sudo find /proc -type l | sudo xargs ls -l | fgrep 'pipe:[29836]') 2>/dev/null
lr-x------ 1 gdm  gdm  64 Jun 20 07:27 /proc/1105/fd/16 -> pipe:[29836]
l-wx------ 1 gdm  gdm  64 Jun 20 07:27 /proc/1105/fd/17 -> pipe:[29836]
```

At the end of the journalctl output I see

```
Jun 20 07:48:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (WW) modeset(0): flip queue failed: Permission denied
Jun 20 07:48:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (WW) modeset(0): Page flip failed: Permission denied
Jun 20 07:48:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (EE) modeset(0): present flip failed
Jun 20 07:49:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (WW) modeset(0): flip queue failed: Permission denied
Jun 20 07:49:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (WW) modeset(0): Page flip failed: Permission denied
Jun 20 07:49:00 dannas--dell-xp-15 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (EE) modeset(0): present flip failed
```

This is the gdm-x-session controlling the Xorg program that is consuming 200% cpu.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with troubleshooting?
Is it expected that there should be two Xorg instances?
How are the Xorg instances created? Which configuration file controls them?

If I kill that Xorg, then there's only one Xorg left which consumes the normal amount of cpu 1-10% and I can continue using my computer.